# Are web services parameters mandatory or optional by default?

Tags: java, web-services

I've built web services using JAX-WS API. My webmethod would look like this:

```
@WebMethod
public String getLocation(@WebParam(name = "token") String p_token, @WebParam(name = "code") String p_code) {...}
```

I just want to know whether web services parameters are mandatory or optional by default? Or does it depend on the client that call web services? I can't find a clear answer from the net.

Using SoapUI, it shows that both parameters are optional. I can call the method omitting any of the parameters without any problem.

Using VB.Net, I need to provide both parameters, empty string is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Eg consider : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

```
    <s:element name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Celsius" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

based on the minOccurs and maxOccurs value we decide SOAP Request.
In this case as minOccurs is 0, so SOAP request is hold good without this element, This Element is optional.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
   <web:CelsiusToFahrenheit>     

      </web:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```